# Open another activity from inside the tab activity

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, tabview

I created a tabbed application in which I have three tabs.
In the first activity I am opening a class named Home.class and inside the Home.class I want to start another activity that should open in that tab itself is it possible.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start multiple Activity in one tab, you need to extend your tab with `ActivityGroup`. and when are you starting new Activity you need to use `startChildActivity`

Comment: There is nothing in this link

Comment: Doesn't it download sample project?

Comment: there is problem with your browser then.. right click and save as

Answer (score 2):

[ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html) is deprecated, try to use [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) and [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use Android ActivityGroup within TabHost to show different Activity